# Using $(warning) inside Android.mk shows a false error in Eclipse. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, android-ndk, eclipse-adt, ndk-build, android.mk

I'm working on an Android project, using the Eclipse ADT environment provided by Google. This project has a somewhat complex `Android.mk` file, that can be easily misconfigured.
In order to ensure correct build flow and output warning and diagnostic messages to the console output, I rely on the `$warning()` command.

The `$warning()` commands are working fine, with the expected output being shown in the Build console; however, the Eclipse IDE is flagging the lines where I invoke the `$warning()` commands as having errors. These errors are propagating hierarchically to the Project Explorer Navigation window, where the `Android.mk` and the `jni` folder are also shown as having errors.

Here is an example of a command that triggers an error:

```
$(warning value of BUILD_CONFIG IS '$(BUILD_CONFIG)')
```

**Although everything is working as expected, I'm being a little pedantic and would like to remove these false errors from the IDE. Is this possible?**

Comment: Eclipse IDE will give lots of false errors in your development process and this is just the beginning of them. For most of the time, I had to force remove the error messages to get the program compiling. Then, I switched to Nvidia Nsight on Visual Studio. Way better than Eclipse in terms of ease of use and native debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$(info)` instead of `$(warning)`. Note that even these innocent messages will ruin the native debugging setup `ndk-gdb`; I use them only conditionally, e.g.

```
ifeq ($V,1)
  $(info value of BUILD_CONFIG IS '$(BUILD_CONFIG)')
endif
```